# use get_followers_ids with lookup_user

Tags: python, twitter, twython

I have a list of id's stored as type dict_values. I want to use this list as input for lookup-user, but the format doesn't seem to be correct. I know that lookup_user normally accepts a string of comma separated values. Is there any way to convert my list of dict-values into this format?

Here is my code so far:

```
import sys
import string
import simplejson
from twython import Twython

import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
day=int(now.day)
month=int(now.month)
year=int(now.year)

twitter = Twython()

out_file_name = "1339835893_follower_ids_%i.%i.%i.txt" % (now.month,
                                                    now.day,
                                                    now.year)

followers = twitter.get_followers_ids(id = "1339835893") # or just () - followers for your account
#print(followers)
#for follower_id in followers:

keys = followers.viewkeys()
values = followers.viewvalues()
print values.__class__

users = twitter.lookup_user(user_id = values) # breaks here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm hoping you've figured out an answer for your question already. In case you haven't, here is a quick answer.

You're passing a dict_values object as the parameter for user_id. This field takes either a list of ids or a string of comma separated ids. See: https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/lookup for more info on the function.

A quick change which works on my end is to change:

```
users = twitter.lookup_user(user_id = values) # breaks here
```

into:

```
users = twitter.lookup_user(user_id=followers['ids'])
```

Since the followers object is a dictionary, you can retrieve the field by indexing it with 'ids'. (You can also use a followers.get('ids') if you'd prefer. Anyways, this returns the list that twython and twitter want!